# Firefox or IE crashes when I try to print

Tags: browser, printing, crash

When I try to print a web page in either IE or Firefox - it just crashes? Any ideas?

Printer works with other applications fine - like Word etc.  It's only browser related for some strange reason.

I am running XP SP3 - the printer is a Canon Laser Shot LBP 1120

Comment: i know this was a while ago but the same issue exists for the LBP 1110. In its case, you download the driver and then a patch. All instructions are in Japanese (maybe the model was never sold abroad?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vidar... Giles here again. Further to my comments above, I have now put my pc back to the restore point just before my ie8 upgrade. It made no difference. Print crashes in all browsers as before.

Before that the original problem I had was that Firefox was defaulting as my main browser and I was doing some website work. All my HTML files were being saved as Firefox files and I wanted them saved as IE files. So I ticked two options in Firefox and IE to reverse this, to make IE my default browser.

To see if this action caused the crashes, I then tried to go back to the restore point before this - but IE and Firefox won't even boot up under that restore point.

At one point IE error message told me it was a DEP problem but I reticked the DEP boxes and now it doesn't give me that error message. Still crashes, tho.

So I am stumped. That's the best I can do.

Comment: SORTED!   Took half a day.   It IS the Canon LBP-1120 that is the problem. Read Firefox error data here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=512554 for confirmation. I can print with a different printer.  Don't know why it happened.

Comment: AND FINALLY -  checking on Canon's website, they posted a correcte driver to download on 23.9.09. That should sort it

Comment: Thanks very much Giles - I will try this when I get home at the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uninstall and reinstall Firefox? Sometimes this helps.

Questions: 
Is this a new Firefox version this is happening on, or your first Firefox? Did it ever work before? Is this problem connected to some other manipulations you did, like install software or drivers? Does the printer work with other software?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Firefox in safe mode.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Good point. I've rephrased the post.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a report from support forum, that installing CAPT DEP-supported
modification module from Canon (
http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0035137.asp ) resolves this issue and
prevents browser crash.
if it's ok let me know.